# Azure / R-server - rxKmeans write file with no header

Tags: r, azure, azure-data-lake, revoscaler, rxkmeans

I'm doing a kmeans clustering in Azure / R-server and need to be able to write a file that does not have a header.

So far I've tried:

```
k1 <- rxKmeans(formula = ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = df, seed = 10, numClusters = 5
               , outFile = dfOut, extraVarsToWrite = c('CUST_ID'), overwrite = T
                , outColName = F
)
```

And I get this error :

```
Error in rxuHandleClusterJobTryFailure(retObject, hpcServerJob, autoCleanup) : 
  Error completing job on cluster:
Error : rxIsCharacterScalarNonEmpty(outColName) is not TRUE
```

I've also tried:

```
k1 <- rxKmeans(formula = ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = df, seed = 10, numClusters = 5
               , outFile = dfOut, extraVarsToWrite = c('CUST_ID'), overwrite = T
                , header = F
)
```

Which returns:

```
Error in rxuHandleClusterJobTryFailure(retObject, hpcServerJob, autoCleanup) : 
  Error completing job on cluster:
Error in rxKmeansBase(formula = formula, data = data, outDataSource = outDataSource,  : 
  unused argument (header = FALSE)
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why did you add the Azure-data-lake tag?

Comment: @MichaelRys : the destination of the output is an Azure data lake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was giving conflicting instructions in the file definition and the rxKmeans function.

I fixed it by omitting the `header` argument from the rxKmeans function and set `firstRowIsColNames` to FALSE.

```
kmeansFile <- paste('~/clusters/ClusterOutput.tsv', sep = '')
dfOut <- RxTextData(kmeansFile, fileSystem = hdfsFS, firstRowIsColNames = F)

k1 <- rxKmeans(formula = ~ var1 + var2 + var3, data = df, seed = 10, numClusters = 5
               , outFile = dfOut, extraVarsToWrite = c('id_num'), overwrite = T
               # , outColName = F
               # , header = F
)
```